# Logo image is failing to render in react app. Module Parse Failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a rect component. I am trhying to render an image in the component. I am getting an issue as I am trying to load and render my Logo into the component. I am getting a parse fail and I am not sure why I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
    at eval (splittlogo_logo_transparent.png:1)
    at Object../client/dist/splittlogo_logo_transparent.png (bundle.js:96)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at eval (topbar.jsx:13)
    at Object../client/src/components/topbar/topbar.jsx (bundle.js:120)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at eval (App.jsx:13)
    at Object../client/src/components/App.jsx (bundle.js:108)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at eval (index.jsx:9)
```

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Logo from '../../../dist/splittlogo_logo_transparent.png'

export default class TopBar extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props),
        this.state = {
          product:"",
        }
      }

    userSearch(e){
        console.log(e.target.value)
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="topbar-coutainer">
                <div className="logo-container">
                    <img src={Logo} alt=""/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input onChange={(e) => {this.userSearch(e)}} type="text" name="search" />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

the path to the logo is correct

this is my webpack:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require('webpack')
require("fs")

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "./client/src/"),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./client/dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        loader: "babel-loader",
        test: /\.js[x]?/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          presets: ["react", "env"]
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          { loader: "style-loader" },
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              modules: true,
              localIdentName: '[hash:base64]'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ], 
  },
  node: {
    fs: 'empty'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx"]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.HOSTNAME': JSON.stringify("localhost"),
      'process.env.PORT': JSON.stringify(1111),
    })
  ]
};
```

Now My webpack should be working properly because I am using the same webpack configuration on a different project and it is properly displaying images where I need it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your webpack configuration is not set up to load images, so when it tries to parse the .png, it dies. You should configure a rule for `file-loader`:

```
 {
    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {},
      },
    ],
  }
```

...or similar.

> Now My webpack should be working properly because I am using the same webpack configuration on a different project and it is properly displaying images where I need it to.

Not sure how to answer this except to say that it doesn't seem possible, as this webpack config simply won't handle images.